# What do we call this?

Tags: php, naming

I'm wondering what do we call this kind of assignment.

```
<?php
class SimpleClass
{
    public $var1;
    public $var2;
    public $var3;

    public function SimpleClass()
    {
        $this->var1 = 'one';
        $this->var2 = 'two';
        $this->var3 = 'three';
    }
}

function test()
{
    $objSc = new SimpleClass();
    $objSc->var4 = 'WTF?!'; # <-- what do we call this?
    var_dump($objSc);
}

test();
?>
```

Better with references or links.  Thanks in advance!

EDIT: I'm looking for a technical term for it... well, if we have.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I believe this is overloading.

> Overloading in PHP provides means to dynamically "create" properties and methods. These dynamic entities are processed via magic methods one can establish in a class for various action types.
>
> **The overloading methods are invoked when interacting with properties or methods that have not been declared or are not visible in the current scope.**

PHP Manual reference [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php).

Comment: The call to set the `var4` property of the `$objSc` object goes via the __set() magic method which you can set yourself to do other things too.

Answer (score 2):

It is **assigning** the **string** `WTF?!` to a public scope variable of `SimpleClass`. If you `var_dump` it, it shows the output correctly as:

```
string(5) "WTF?!"
```

And as @marcdev pointed out, it is known as **overloading**.

Answer (score 1):

You are setting an independent property of the `$objSc` object.